# Is there a way to not charge customer until the order has "shipped"?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, authorize.net, fedex

Client requested to have it set up this way a few days before going live. Not sure how to accomplish this. We are using auth.net and fedex shipping. Any ideas?

Essentially take credit card info but don't charge for the product or shipping until the product has shipped or is ready to ship.

Comment: You can authorize a card for up to 30 days on Authorize.net at which time they will release the funds. Most other card processors we've worked with over the years have the same or shorter period. Stripe for instance will only authorize and hold for 14 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this currently is to set card transactions to Authorize Only. They will then be pending orders until you Capture the funding when you generate the Magento Invoice and Shipment simultaneously.

You will need to make sure that Authorize.Net allows for the Authorize/Capture cycle, we found them to be the most inflexible credit card processor out there.